# Can I limit the number of data to migrate in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, database-migration

I just like to ask if it is possible to limit the number of data that I will migrate on the new db version. For example, if I have 100 objects in my Food table, I want to migrate only 10 of them in the new db.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use *light-weight migration* there is no provision to limit the amount of records that are migrated. That means there is no *automatic* way you could include in a schema migration.

However, you can of course keep track which version your users are using (very simply with `NSUserPreferences`) and then if a version change is detected simply delete the records you do not want. Just fetch these records (filtering with a predicate, or limiting them with a `fetchLimit` of your fetch request), iterate through the results, `deleteObject:` and `save:`.